# Как запустить одновременно два потока?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Как можно запустить одновременно два потока (не дожидаясь завершения одного из них) на Java?

Comment: Так никто их и так не ждёт...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - просто создать и запустить потоки:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(Foo::foo).start();
        new Thread(() -> bar()).start();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                baz();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    static void foo() { /* долгая задача 1 */ }
    static void bar() { /* долгая задача 2 */ }
    static void baz() { /* долгая задача 3 */ }
}
```

Но в реальной жизни обычно так не делают.

---

Решение лучше и гибче - использовать пул потоков и отправлять в него задачи:

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        pool.submit(Foo::foo);
        pool.submit(() -> bar());
        pool.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                baz();
            }
        });
    }

    static void foo() { /* долгая задача 1 */ }
    static void bar() { /* долгая задача 2 */ }
    static void baz() { /* долгая задача 3 */ }
}
```

Comment: Ответ хорош, но от себя внесу небольшую лепту. Пусть автор вопроса для начала разберется с третьим вариантом создания потоков: new Thread(new Runnable() ... . Первые два варианта сложнее по конструкции (особенно для начинающего).